# Problem on configuring vscode for C#: it doesn't generate launch.json and tasks.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to prepare C# debugging environment with vscode. I'm following [Tutorial: Create a .NET console application using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0). However, nothing happens when I select ".NET 5+ and .NET Core" after configured console app.

[image]

The document I'm reffering says as follows:

> Note
>
> If you don't get the prompt, or if you accidentally dismiss it without selecting Yes, do the following steps to create launch.json and tasks.json:
>
> Select Run > Add Configuration from the menu.
> Select .NET 5+ and .NET Core at the Select environment prompt.

I followed the instruction but nothing happened. No json, no error or log, no clue.
How can I setup vscode for C#?

note: I tried this on multiple computers (win10/win11). Same result on all computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vscode asked me after RESTART vscode as follows:
[image: Required assets to build and debug are missing from 'your project'. Add them?]

Clicking Yes let it generate json files, allows run and debug.

note: default configuration doesn't allow standard input. So I changed console setting to integratedTerminal from internalConsole as follows:

[image: launch.json]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by updating to the previous version of the C# extension.(Ex-ID: ms-dotnettools.csharp).
[Getting previous version on VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l0FJ.png)

Comment: After that, this may required  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4QnK.png)

Answer (score 0):

From time to time I also encountered similar problem. I don't know exactly why the extension doesn't generate the required files (`.vscode` folder and its contents.

Another alternative is to force the extension by invoking the command `dotnet.generateAssets`. The command correctly created the required files.

[image]